# Вывод двумерного массива в файл

Tags: c++

```
FILE *f=fopen ("1.txt","w");
  for (int i=0;i<n;  i++)
       for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
           fprintf (f,"%d", matrix[i][j]); 
       }
```

мне нужно вывести матрицу n*n, а всё выводится в одну строчку, что неправильно?

Comment: Вы не добавляете перевод строки после каждой строки массива. Во внешнем цикле добавьте fprintf(f, "\n");

Comment: @fori1ton, где именно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так

```
 for (int i=0;i<n;  i++) {
   for (int j=0;j<n;j++){
       fprintf (f,"%d", matrix[i][j]); 
    }
    putc ('\n', f);
 }
```